# How to binding dropdown in html5 page using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to know the code for binding drop down in HTML5 using Jquery.

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ti need to know binding drop down with SQL table data into HTML page using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this::

```
     <ul class="mian-nav">
            <li class="has-dropdown">1
                 <ul class="subnav">
                    <li class="has-dropdown">1.1</li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">1.2</li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">2</li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">3</li>
        </ul>
```

jQuery::

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".subnav").hide();
 jQuery(".has-dropdown").click(function(){
   jQuery(this).children('.subnav').toggle();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This code is working but i need to know binding drop down with SQL table data into HTML page using JQuery?

Comment: @Rushda  why then you marked this answer? this means that you got solution of your problem

Comment: @Rushda you can modify dropdown according to sql data using loops.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Do you have any examples according to using loops in SQL data?